# add a column to a dataframe using ifelse

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I'm trying to add a new column at the end by referencing data within the dataframe. I can get the ifelse to work and show in the console but the column isn't being added to the dataframe so when I print the dataframe, it just has the original columns. Here is what I have:

```
stats <- read.csv("name.csv")
stats

colnames(stats)


library(dplyr)

stats %>%
 mutate(newColumn = 
           ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201503,  "2015_16", 
           ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201508,  "2015_16", 
            ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201510,  "2015_16",
            ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201601, "2015_16",
            ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201603 & ExistingColumn == 2018, "2016_17",
            ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201603 & ExistingColumn == 2019, "2016_17", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201608 & ExistingColumn == 2018, "2016_17", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201610 & ExistingColumn == 2018, "2016_17",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201701 & ExistingColumn == 2018, "2016_17",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201703 & ExistingColumn == 2018, "2016_17",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201703 & ExistingColumn == 2019, "2017_18", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201708, "2017_18", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201710, "2017_18",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201801, "2017_18",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201803 & ExistingColumn == 2019, "2017_18",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201803 & ExistingColumn == 2020, "2018_19", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201808, "2018_19", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201810, "2018_19", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201901, "2018_19", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201903 & ExistingColumn == 2020, "2018_19",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201903 & ExistingColumn == 2021, "2019_20", 
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201908, "2019_20",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 201910, "2019_20",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202001, "2019_20",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202003 & ExistingColumn == 2021, "2019_20",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202003 & ExistingColumn == 2022, "2020_21",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202008, "2020_21",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202010, "2020_21",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202101, "2020_21",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202103 & ExistingColumn == 2022, "2020_21",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202103 & ExistingColumn == 2023, "2021_22",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202108, "2021_22",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202110, "2021_22",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202201, "2021_22",
              ifelse(columnInDataframe == 202203 & ExistingColumn == 2023, "2021_22", NA)
              )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

print(stats)
```

The ultimate goal is to have this column be added to a spreadsheet but I can't even get it to show up in the dataframe.

Comment: Create a key value data.frame and do a join instead of multiple nested ifelse.  You haven't assigned output back to the dataset .e. `stats <- stats %>% ...`

Comment: If using dplyr, consider `case_when` instead of `ifelse`, its much less verbose/more compact